# Is there a way to determine an element by its path or full url instead of the uri?

Tags: plugin-development, modules, controller, request, headless

I'm using Craft in headless mode. It's a multisite setup different languages. I know that's it's possible to query an element by it's uri. Is there a way to check if a full path or an absolute url matches an craft element inside an module or plugin controller action?

For example i would like to check i a path like this examples matches an element on any site and return the entry and site:

```
/my-example-element
/de/my-example-element
```

Is there any helper or built in method where i can pass the path and retrieve the matching element?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the search function -> https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/searching.html which works excellent, especially via GraphQl. If you need to query for full Urls I would probably strip it to the pathname using `URL` in your application before sending it to Craft for searching.
I hope I understood your question correctly ...